# While-loops school assignment

Tags: loops, while-loop

This assignment consists of two tasks.

Task 1:

a) Create a program that reads numbers from the user until the user provides the number 0. (Without doing anything with numbers). Use a while loop to achieve this.

I made this code to achieve this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloPrinter {   
public static void main(String[] args)   {     
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int ditt_tall = 1;

while(ditt_tall != 0)  {

    System.out.print("Skriv inn ditt tall:  ");
    ditt_tall = in.nextInt();


    }           
}
```

}

This is the task in task 2:

b) Expand the program to sum all the numbers from the user (until user
give the number 0) and write the result to the terminal

To be honest. I have no idea what to do. Can someone give me a hint or expand the first code so it works the way it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a variable to save the total, before your while loop starts and set it to zero.  Inside your loop, accept the input and add it to your total value.  After the loop ends, print out your total variable value.

So, in addition to your

> int ditt_tall = 1;

create your total variable there too, like

> int ditt_total = 0;

inside your loop, you can increment the total with the value that is input:

> ditt_total = ditt_total + ditt_tall;

And after the loop ends, print out the value of ditt_total.

Go through the code by hand, pretending to input numbers, and seeing how ditt_tall and ditt_total change with each loop.  Using paper is a good way to understand what the program is doing, and also helps figure out what is going wrong when the results are not what you expect.

Here are some things to consider, however: what happens if the user enters a string or decimal number?  Maybe at this point you don't have to deal with that, but bad input is a problem you'll always need to consider in real life.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know how to make a variabel save the total of the inputs when inputs can be 2 or 100.

Is there a special method for that or something?

Comment: Tried **this** now, but it is not working:

`import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloPrinter {   
 public static void main(String[] args)   {     
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int ditt_tall = 1;
  int total = 0;
  
 while(ditt_tall != 0)  {
  
  total = (ditt_tall + ditt_tall);
  
  System.out.print("Skriv inn ditt tall:  ");
  ditt_tall = in.nextInt();
 
  
  } 
 
 System.out.print(ditt_tall);
 }    
}`

Comment: Your total is twice what you input, each time.  You want a running total, so your formula within your loop would be better as total = total + ditt_tall.  And then at the end, print the total.  Right now, you're printing your last input, which would be 0.